# How can i include only specific styles and scripts for a wordpress page template?

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I am building a custom page template for wordpress and i want to only include specific styles and scripts and completely ignore the activated theme styles and scripts so they don't conflict with my design.

How can i just allow specific styles and scripts and ignore all the styles and scripts of activated wordpress theme?

Comment: use conditional, for default styles and scripts in index.php ?

Comment: I am building this for a client so i don't know what styles or what themes he will be using, i just need to find a way to just only allow specific styles and scripts relevant to my page template and ignore everything else.

Comment: use $REQUEST conditional in your index. OR try to search a plugin . I prefer second option

Comment: You can dequeue scripts and styles that are enqueued in the theme, plugins etc, *but* you need to know the handle they were enqueued with. Otherwise they are going to be loaded by Wordpress so there's not much you can do.

Comment: Yes i have already tried that and i was hoping there maybe something out there that can fix this issue for me.

If there is nothing then i may have to include the styles and scripts manually and exclude <?php wp_head(); ?> from the page template.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you.

```
function register_foundation_style() {
  if ( is_page_template( 'template-registration-page.php' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'foundation', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/foundation/css/foundation.min.css' );
  }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_foundation_style'
```

Ref: https://dobsondev.com/2015/06/05/conditionally-enqueue-stylesheet-into-wordpress-for-certain-page/

Comment: That doesn't address the OP's issue, which it that they want to be able to dequeue other styles and scripts without knowing what they might be.

Comment: Yes it would be ideal once we enqueue styles or scripts conditionally it would automatically ignore other styles and scripts.

Answer (score 0):

As there is no way to accomplish this, i manage to do this small hack and it works just fine.

I removed `<?php wp_head(); ?>` from my template and i manually included the css file like this.

```
<?php 
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' . plugins_url( 'assets/css/style.css', __FILE__ ) . '" type="text/css" media="screen" />';
?>
```